# Formal description

Tags: logic

Does anyone know how can I rewrite the following expression using a logical language(universal/existential quantifier, and, or, not, ...):

> E:= ,,The same room cannot be used at the same time by more than one course during a particular semester''

Is E elementary or could be split further in elementarer propositions?

Comment: I suspect they want you to treat "usage" as a binary predicate, with inputs of time and course, and show that for each time there is exactly 1 course (i.e. that the predicate is a function wrt time).

Comment: @DanielV Could you give me an example expression, then transforming it using binary predicates

Comment: For example, if $C$ was the set of courses, $T$ is the set of all times, and  $U$ means "to use", then "there is a time when every course can use the room" would be $\exists t \in T ~:~ \forall c \in C ~:~ U(t,c)$